# How to write a for loop inside another for loop in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm learning to code with Flask, my issue is that I have a list in a list that looks like this for one product

```
'Title': "abc",
'PriceList': [$5, $5.30]
```

I'm using flask, so I iterate in the list using:

```
{% for item in list %}
<h1> Title: {{item.0}} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is how do I loop into item.1, that is the column 'PriceList'?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
For item in list:
  print(item[0])
  For price in item[1]:
   print(price)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply nest the loops.

```
{% for item in list %}
  <h1> Title: {{item.Title}} </h1>
  <ul>
  {% for price in item.PriceList %} 
    <li>{{ price }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```